# Response.write with classic ASP page on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, vbscript, asp-classic, windows-server-2008, response.write

The following statement will not work with a classic asp page on an IIS7 website

```
<% Response.Write("test") %>
```

Comment: please give more information, what is the Application pool settings for this Website, is it a website application?...

Comment: The application pool settings are set to No Managed Code and Classic.

Answer (score 3):

Have you enabled ASP inside Windows features?

[image]

Comment: I get a blank page. My HTML code for the page shows up just fine (when its included), but the server side response.write shows up blank.

Comment: I created an index.asp file with your code inside it, dropped the file into the default website (.NET Framework v2.0.50727, Integrated) and received the "test" message as output. What kind of pool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it had to do with adding a handler mapping for server side includes. When I added a module mapping ServerSideIncludeModule with request path of *.asp, it broke my site.